# Sync Navigation Bar To View Controller During Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, segue

**PREAMBLE**

VIEW CONTROLLER A: Has no navigation bar.

VIEW CONTROLLER B: Has a navigation bar.

At present: when segueing from VIEW CONTROLLER A to VIEW CONTROLLER B:

The navigation bar just appears [ rather than transitioning in sync with the VIEW CONTROLLER B body ].

**QUESTION**

How do I force the navigation bar to segue in sync with the view controller body ?

Comment: SOLUTION:  Install a nav bar to " View Controller A ". Make said nav bar invisible.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.In view will appear of ViewController A hide navigation bar and viewwilldisappear in ViewController B show navigation bar.and
2.hide navigation bar in ViewControllerA and show navigation bar in ViewController B viewwill appear
3.when you push view controller use animated in the parametes [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewb animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but the navigation bar is still out of sync.